# Equivalent conditions Isomorphism, dual space and $\det C\neq 0 $ ex

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $K$, and let $g$ be a bilinear form on $V$, written $\langle,\rangle$.
> In  the previous part: for each $w\in V$, the map $v\to\langle v,w\rangle$ is a functional $L_w$ on $V$, and  the map $w\to L_w$ is a linear map of $V$ into the dual space $V^{*}$.(This was already proven in a previous exercise).
> Show that the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> (i) The kernel of the map $L$ above is {0}
>
> (ii)The map $L$ is an isomorphism between $V$ and $V^{*}$
>
> (iii) If $C$ is the matrix representing the bilinear form with respect to a basis of $V$, then $\det(C)\neq 0$.
>
> A bilinear form satisfying the preceding three conditions is said to be *non-degenerate.*

I started answering using (ii)

$\dim V=\dim V^{*}$, since w\in V by assumption.

$\ker(L_w)=0$ iff $w=0$

Therefore there exists an isomorphism that was already proven in the book.

(ii) implies (i), since $w\in V$, the $Ker{L}=0$ iff $w=0$ or $v=0$, in which in this case $v=w$. Therefore the $ker{L}=0$ for arbitrary $w$.

I make use of the following theorem for the relation (ii) implies (iii).

> Theorem: Let $F:V\to W$ be a linear map, and assume that F is injective and surjective. Then F is invertible.

Proof:Each $w\in W$ matches a v once F is surjective and and the v is uniquely determined for each w once F is injective. If we consider $G:W\to V$, then $G=F^{-1}$, we need to prove G is linear.

If $w_1,w_2\in W$ then $F(v_1)=w_1$ and $F(v_2)=w_2$ and since F is linear $F(v_1+V_2)=F(v_1)+F(v_2)$ Therefore $G(w_1+w_2)=v_1+v_2=G(v_1)+G(v_2)$.

If $c\in K$ then $F(cv_1)=cF(v_1)=cw_1$. Therefore $G(cw_1)=cv_1=cG(w_1)$ $\blacksquare$

Since the map $w\to L_w$ is an isomorphism by (ii) implies the map is invertible. For an arbitrary bilinear matrix C to be invertible it requires $\det(C)\neq 0$, implying (iii).

**Questions**:

**1)** Is my usage of the mapping $w\to L_w$ correct? Does it solve the question?

**2)** Is my poof right?

**3)** I made used of non-degeneracy in the proof. What is supposed to mean "A bilinear form satisfying the preceding three conditions is said to be *non-degenerate.*"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DietrichBurde It means exercise.

Comment: And what means "the map $L$ above"? I can't find a definition of $L$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I appreciate your attention. My sincere apologies. I forgot to write vital information for the exercise propose. Please check my new edit.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you did not prove the statement.

Let's go in the usual way.

(i)$\implies$(ii) Since $\dim V=\dim V^*$ and $L\colon V\to V^*$ is injective (having zero kernel), it is also surjective, hence an isomorphism.

(ii)$\implies$(iii) Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be a basis of $V$; the matrix $C=[c_{ij}]$ is defined by $c_{ij}=\langle v_i,v_j\rangle$. Let's compute the matrix of $L$ with respect to $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ and $\{v_1^*,\dots,v_n^*\}$ (the dual basis). By definition, we need to express $L_{v_i}$ as a linear combination of the vectors in the dual basis:
$$
L_{v_i}=\alpha_{1}v_1^*+\dots+\alpha_{n}v_n^*
$$
Now, for $j=1,2,\dots,n$,
$$
L_{v_i}(v_j)=\alpha_1v_1^*(v_j)+\dots+\alpha_nv_n^*(v_j)=\alpha_j
$$
so $\alpha_j=\langle v_i,v_j\rangle$.

We conclude the requested matrix is exactly $C$ (or $C^T$ depending on conventions); the matrix associated to an isomorphism is invertible.

(iii)$\implies$(i) Take $v\in\ker L$ and…

Comment: How would you go from (iii) to (i)?

Comment: After reading more carefully your proof.$ L_{v_i}(v_j)=\alpha_1v_1^*(v_j)+\dots+\alpha_nv_n^*(v_j)=\alpha_j$ only if the basis of $V$ is an orthogonal basis, which is not assumed.

Comment: @PedroGomes By definition, $v_i^*(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$. No orthogonality, which makes no sense here: $\{v_1^*,\dots,v_n^*\}$ is, by assumption, the *dual basis* of $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$.

Comment: It was just because $L_{v_i}(v_j)=\alpha_1v_1^*(v_j)+\dots+\alpha_nv_n^*(v_j)=\alpha_j$ in which $\alpha_j$ is a constant  so that $a_j\langle v_j,v^{*}_j\rangle=a_j$ and if $j\neq i$ then $a_j\langle v_i,v^{*}_j\rangle=0$. That is the reason why I thought you assumed ortoghonality or another functional. Why write $a_j$ and now write $v_i^*(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$?

Comment: @PedroGomes $\delta_{ij}$ is customary notation for $\delta_{ii}=1$ and $\delta_{ij}=0$ for $i\ne j$. You should know about the dual basis in $V^*$ corresponding to a basis of $V$.

Comment: I thought that was a technique to find the dual basis and prove some theorems. That would not imply I think the transformation matrix to be a diagonal matrix?

Comment: @PedroGomes Sorry, but I can't follow. The dual basis is defined in terms of the given basis, exactly by $v_i^*$ being the unique functional such that $v_i^*(v_j)=\begin{cases}1&i=j\\0&i\ne j\end{cases}$. The bilinear form is given by the problem and is not tied to the dual basis.

Comment: Otherwise you would get no value for $\langle v_i,v_j \rangle$ if $i\neq j$, right? That is not true, you must get a value.

Comment: Yes you are right. What about $\langle v,w\rangle$, you will get a value despite the fact they may coincide or not, right?

Comment: @PedroGomes As I said, the bilinear form is *given*.

Comment: What is the bilinear form on this case? The dual basis times the vector space basis?

Comment: @PedroGomes Stop, please. Your problem *begins with* “Let $g$ be a bilinear form…”.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the bilinear matrix $C$? What is $C$?

Comment: @PedroGomes Your book should tell you it's the one I defined in my answer.