# Functional on $V\times W$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $g:V\times W\to K$ be a bilinear map written $\langle ,\rangle$. For each $w\in W$, the map of $V$ into $K$ given by:
>
> $L_w:v\mapsto\langle v,w\rangle$ is a functional on $V$, and that map $w\mapsto L_w$ is a linear map of $W$ into the dual space of $V^{*}$.
>
> Show that the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> (i) The map $L:W\to V^*$ is injective (its kernel is $\{0\}$).
>
> (ii) If $C$ is a matrix associated with $g$, then $C$ has a rank $n$, where $n=\dim W$.

(i) $w\mapsto L_w$ is an injective map iff $\ker L=0$

By non degeneracy property

If $v\in V$ and $v\neq 0$.

$L_w(v)=\langle v,w\rangle=0$ iff $w=0$ $\implies \ker(L_w)=0$.

If we consider $\mathscr{B},\mathscr{B}^*$ to be the bases of $V$ and $V^*$

$c_{ij}=g(\mathscr{B},\mathscr{B}^*)=\langle \mathscr{B},\mathscr{B}^*\rangle$

Therefore $c_{ij}$ gives rise to a diagonal matrix of dimension $n$.

By a previous theorem it is proven $\dim V=\dim V^*\implies \dim V^*=n$

As $L:W\to V*$ is injective then $\dim W=n$.

**Questions**:

**1)** How can we know "$L:W\to V^*$ is injective then $\dim W=n$"? We need an isomorphism right? However (I) does not require an isomorphism.

**2)** Is my proof right? I feel there are steps not well justified as the last one.

**3)** Is Matrix C a diagonal matrix?

**4)** Can someone help me correct or provide me an alternative proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You write that $w \mapsto L_w$ is a linear map of $W$ into the dual space **of** $V^{*}$; did you meant "into the dual space, $V^{*}$?

Comment: Are you given that $V$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: @JohnHughes $w\to L_w$ is a map of $W$ into the dual space as you asked. $V$ is finite dimensional. Sorry if there was any misunderstanding. I was away of the discussion but now I am back. I am going to study the case and give feed-back. Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\newcommand{\bv}{{\mathbf v}}
\newcommand{\bw}{{\mathbf w}}
\newcommand{\bC}{{\mathbf C}}
\newcommand{\bz}{{\mathbf 0}}
\newcommand{\bx}{{\mathbf x}}
$$
Your proof is wrong. It assumes non-degeneracy, which is not given in the hypotheses of the problem. It assumes $V$ is finite dimensional, which is not given in the hypotheses. It refers to "the bases" of $V$ and $V*$, but unless $V$ has dimension zero, or the underlying field is very small (like $F_2$), there are many possible bases for $V$ and $V*$.

As for providing an alternative proof...I might consider providing one, but only once you answer the clarifying questions I've asked.

---

Suppose that $L$ is injective.

Pick bases $\bw_1, \ldots, \bw_n$ of $W$, and a basis $\bv_1, \ldots, \bv_k$ of $V$ (which we can do because both are finite-dimensional).

Let $c_{ij} = g(\bv_i, \bw_j)$ for $i = 1, \ldots, k; j = 1, \ldots, n$.

Suppose that the rank of $C$ is some number $p$ less than $n$; then there is some nontrivial linear combination of the $n$ columns of $c$ whose value is zero, i.e., there are constants $s_1, \ldots, s_n$, not all zero, with 
$$
s_1 \bC_1 + s_2 \bC_2 + \ldots + s_n \bC_n = \bz,
$$
where $C_i$ denotes the $i$th column of $C$. The $j$th row of the equation above says that 
$$
s_1 c_{j1} + \ldots + s_n c_{jn} = 0.
$$
This must hold for $j = 1, \ldots, k$.

Now substituting the definition of $c_{ij}$, we get
$$
s_1 g(\bv_j, \bw_1) + \ldots + s_n g(\bv_j, \bw_n) = 0,
$$
which, by bilinearity of $g$, gives 
$$
g(\bv_j, s_1 \bw_1 + \ldots + s_n \bw_n) = 0
$$
for all $j$.

Letting $\bx = s_1 \bw_1 + \ldots + s_n \bw_n$, which is nonzero because the $\bw$s form a basis and not all $s_j$ are zero, we have
$$
g(\bv_j, \bx) = 0
$$
for all $j$, Hence for any coefficients $t_i$, we have
$$
g(\sum_i t_j \bv_j , \bx) = 0
$$
and since the $\bv$s are a basis for $V$, this shows that $g(., \bx)$ is everywhere zero on $V$, or to say it differently, shows that $L_\bx$ is the $\bz$ element of $V^{*}$, contradicting the claim that $L$ is injective.

---

Now forget all the symbols used in the previous part except for the bases $\{\bv_i\}$ and $\{\bw_j\}$.

Now suppose that $L$ is *not* injective. I'll show that the rank of the matrix is less than $n$.

Because $L$ is not injective, we have $L_{\mathbf a} = L_{\mathbf b}$ for some distinct $\mathbf a, \mathbf b$. Let $\bx = \mathbf b - \mathbf a$. Then $L_{\mathbf x} = L_{\mathbf b} - L_{\mathbf a} = 0$. Write $\bx$ as a linear combination of the elements of our basis for $W$: 
$$
\bx = s_1 \bw_1 + \ldots + s_k \bw_k,
$$
and note that not all the $s_i$ are zero (for if they were, $\bx$ would be zero, which is not, because $\mathbf a \ne \mathbf b$).

For every $\bv \in V$, we have $L_\bx(\bv) = 0$. In particular, for $\bv_1, \bv_2, \ldots$, we have $L_\bx(\bv_i) = 0$, whence $g(\bv_i, \bx) = 0$.

Following the same reasoning as before, but in reverse, we get, for $j = 1, \ldots, k$, that
$$
s_1 g(\bv_j, \bw_1) + \ldots + s_n g(\bv_j, \bw_n) = \bz,
$$
and hence
$$
s_1 \bC_1 + \ldots + s_n \bC_n = \bz,
$$
where $\bC_i$ denotes the $i$th column of the matrix $C$. This is a nontrivial relation among the $n$ columns of $C$, hence the set of columns cannot be linearly independent, hence the rank of $C$ (the largest number of linearly independent columns) cannot be $n$.

---

Note that this proof does not rely on $V$ being finite dimensional, i.e., every step works just fine even if $k = \infty$. It only (as written) requires that $V$ have a countable basis. I suspect it could be adjusted slightly to handle the case where $V$ has an "uncountable basis", but then you get into messy details about just what that term might mean, and I don't want to do that.

Comment: I have been studying your answer and your points have risen some doubts. Concerning  only your statement, you actually prove matrix C must have dimension $n$ for the kernel of map $w\to L_w$ to be zero. You pointed out non-degeneracy is not implicit, however I would like to check a previous question in which that property was used in an answer. I want to know if the bilinear form demands non-degeneracy property. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370353/equivalent-conditions-isomorphism-dual-space-and-det-c-neq-0-ex

Comment: I prove nothing about the dimension of C, only its rank. As for your second question: no. There are lots of degenerate bilinear forms. Unless a problem states that the form is nondegenerate, you cannot assume it, just as you cannot assume that an arbitrary function is continuous.

Comment: Have you checked the question I asked? Non-degeneracy is assumed by the person that answers. This is confusing me. Please check that answer!

Comment: I don't need to check that...I KNOW the definition of bilinear form. An answer on mse is *not* gospel...

Comment: So you are saying that the answer is wrong. The problem is that I do not see an alternative proof without the use of the non-degeneracy property. I was thinking if you could kindly provide me one for the other question as you did here. As I said in a previous comment the book usually refers non-degenerate scalar products everytime they talk about functional. Therefore I am not used to proofs that differ from those. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: I am not saying anything about that answer. I'm saying that I know the definition of bilinear form, and that "nondegeneracy" is a property of *some*, but not *all*, bilinear forms, just as continuity is a property of some, but not all, functions from the reals to the reals. At this point, you're asking a different question from the one in the title, and that's just bad behavior on MSE. I've given you a very detailed and complete answer to the question you asked, and that's where I'm stopping.

Comment: Sorry but I am not asking a total different question. I need to trust your answer. This is a way to make you see how others are treating similar questions. So that you understand if there is some kind of mistake in your premise regarding non-degeneracy or on others unawareness of that property, or if others are mistaken. That is no bad behaviour, on the contrary this is good behaviour since my effort intents to get the truth.

Comment: Bless you. You ARE asking a different question. When you started, it was "is my proof right" and "can you give me a correct proof". I've answered both. Now it's shifted to "Is this other answer right?" That's different. As for trusting my answer: The definition of "bilinear form" can be found in hundreds of places on the internet -- just go look for yourself and see whether nondegeneracy is part of the definition. (Hint: it's not.) MY proof doesn't depend in any way on non-degeneracy, so as I said, I'm done here.

Comment: Thank you! I understand your point to be true. I am just a little bit sceptical because of other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the map $L$ is not only injective, but also surjective.

Proof:

Assume that $\exists w, w' \in W$ such that $L(w) = L(w')$, i.e $L_w = L{w'}$, so 
$$\forall v \in V \qquad <v, w> = <v, w'> \Rightarrow <v, w - w'> = 0$$, and by the non-degenerate character of $<,>$, $w=w'$, so $L$ is injective.

And as for your second question, since we have a non-degenerate bilinear function between $V$ and $W$, $V $ and $W$ are dual spaces(see the side note at the end of the answer), so 
$$dim V^* = dim V = dim W$$

In another way, you can also say that, since $L$ is injective
$$dim W \leq V^*.$$
So now consider the other way around, i.e let $L' : V \to W^*$,
since this map will also be injective, we have 
$$dim V \leq W^*$$
So, combining two result with the fact that $dim V = dim V^*$, we get
$$dim V = dim W$$

A side note, the definition of dual space of a vector space is more general than just the space of linear functionals of that vector space $L(V)$.In fact, the exact definition of a dual vector space of $V$ is a vector space $W$ such that there is a non-degenerate bilinear function defined between $V$ and $W$.

Comment: I don't see the assumption that $V$ is finite dimensional anywhere, but $dim V = dim V^{*}$, which you use, relies on that.

Comment: @JohnHughes In the question, it is already assumed $W$ to be finite dimensional, and there is a theorem stating that, if one of the vector spaces in a dual pair is finite, then the dual space is also finite and has the same dimension.

Comment: There's an assumption of finite dimension in one of OP's attempted answers, but nothing about it in the *question*. It only mentions $dim W = n$. (Perhaps you think that "matrix associated with..." implies the dimension is finite but lots of folks work with infinite matrices...)

Comment: @JohnHughes Generally, whenever I see something like "(something) = n", I always assume that that _something_ is finite. In fact, this is what is taught  me in my university as a convention.

Comment: Sure. That makes $W$ finite dimensional. What about $V$?

Comment: @JohnHughes As I have said, "there is a theorem stating that, if one of the vector spaces in a dual pair is finite, then the dual space is also finite and has the same dimension"

Comment: @JohnHughes Don't forgot to read the side note at the end of my answer, and don't forget $W$ and $V$ are dual pair since there is a non-degenerate bilinear function defined between them.

Comment: Let $g : \Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R: ( (x, y), z) \mapsto yz$. This satisfies all the assumptions of the problem, but $V$ and $W$ are not a dual pair. (There's no mention of $\langle, \rangle$ being nondegenerate inthe problem statement, only in the proposed answer.)

Comment: Also...your "side remark" on dual spaces disagrees with my own experience, Hoffman and Kunze's text, and Wikipedia.

Comment: @JohnHughes OP uses in his/her proof that "By non degeneracy property", so I just assumed OP forget to state it in his/her question.

Comment: Yes....but OP also asks if that proof is correct; I think it's *not*, because it assumes things not stated in the problem. My point is that the theorem is true even if the pairing happens to be degenerate ... it's a deeper theorem than you're imagining. How deep? I don't know. In particular, I haven't really worked out the case where $V$ is not finite dimensional.

Comment: @JohnHughes See Werner Greub's linear algebra book. Plus, if you are going to give wikipedia as a source, there is nothing to discuss anymore.

Comment: @JohnHughes I have check the proof of $V^* \cong L(V)$, which is also used in $V \cong V^*$, and it uses the non-degeneracy of the bilinear map, so I can't really say anything about your claim.

Comment: @JohnHughes By way, yes OP does weird things, so I also don't thing his/her proof is correct.

Comment: OK; discount Wikipedia then --- you've got one linear algebra book as an example for your definition. I've got one too. And I've got another -- Gelfand's. Greub's notion seems more like that of a "dual pairing" than the dual space, but without the book, I can't be certain. But back to the main point: we still don't seem to know what the actual question is that the OP was asking. But (at least in the finite-dimensional case) if nondegeneracy were assumed, then the map $L$ would automatically be injective, so it'd be weird to show that it's equivalent to something else, no?

Comment: @JohnHughes If I understood correctly what you mean, yes it would be weird .

Comment: @JohnHughes About the dual spaces, I know most of the books considers dual space as  just $L(E)$, but you can see that with the Greub's definition, $L(E)$ is also included as a dual space and more, and if you want a source for it, you can look at the questions about the dual spaces in this website, there is heck a lot, and you can see that this general definition of dual space is much more useful if you read the Greub's book.

Comment: Well...more useful to *some* folks. The L(V) definition suffices just fine for all the algebraic topology stuff I used to do, for instance. I personally like definitions that say things like  "$X$ is *the* dual space" rather than "$X$ is *a* dual space", because when someone says "let $u$ be in the dual space," you know what they're talking about. But that's a matter of taste.

Comment: @JohnHughes And probably for that very reason, the definition of _dual_ space is giving as $L(E)$.

Comment: I find it hard to reconcile that with "the definition of dual space of a vector space is more general than just the space of linear functionals of that vector space." YMMV.

Comment: @JohnHughes YMMV  ?

Comment: "Your mileage may vary", a statement included in many automobile advertisements in the US, explaining that the rated mileage and the actual mileage might differ. Used here as a shorthand way to say "Things may be different for you than they are for me, and perhaps these two statements, which seem contradictory to me, do not in fact appear to you to be contradictory, but that's just life. "

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess you are confused how is $L(V)$ is a dual space with my definition ? Lets define a bilinear map as $<f,x> = f(x),$ where $f\in L(V), x \in V$.it can easily be seen that this map is non-degenerate, so $V, L(V)$ are dual pairs.

Comment: No, I understood that completely. I'm now bowing out of this discussion.

Comment: @JohnHughes From what I know about dual spaces at least what is defined in my book, is that non-degeneracy is associated with a non-degenerate scalar product. That is what my book assumes for all the theorems about dual spaces. Sorry if doubts have raised because of my absence on this discussion.